# Using unix command and awk to reformat table (groupby)

Tags: unix, awk

The following 5 columns table holds in cols1-3 **location** information, 
col4 holds the **type of hits within location** (there are 3 possible types- with serial numbers: 1,2,3), and col5 holds the **number of hits** of the specific type (may be zero, or any number of hits).

Note, that there are a few locations that have multiple types of hits.
For ex. location [chrX 93554661 94234661] has 5 hits of type '2', 
and 3 hits of type '3'.

```
chrX    93554661    94234661    2   5
chrX    93554661    94234661    3   3
chrX    94234661    94674661    1   1
chrX    95044661    96804661    1   4
chrX    95044661    96804661    2   1
chrX    95044661    96804661    3   6
chrX    96804661    97684661    1   4
chrX    97684661    98964661    1   3
chrX    98964661    99724661    0   0
chrX    99724661    101124661   1   4
chrX    101124661   101524661   1   4
chrX    101524661   103124661   1   5
chrX    101524661   103124661   3   1
chrX    103124661   103444661   3   2
chrX    103444661   104044661   1   1
chrX    103444661   104044661   2   4
```

I'd like to reformat the table so that in the new table the three most right columns would represent the total number of hits from each type in each location, such that columns 4,5,6 will represent serial hit types 1,2,3, respectively.

The desirable format is:

```
chrX    93554661    94234661    0   5   3
chrX    94234661    94674661    1   0   0
chrX    95044661    96804661    4   1   6
chrX    96804661    97684661    4   0   0
chrX    97684661    98964661    3   0   0
chrX    98964661    99724661    0   0   0
chrX    99724661    101124661   4   0   0
chrX    101124661   101524661   4   0   0
chrX    101524661   103124661   5   0   1
chrX    103124661   103444661   0   0   2
chrX    103444661   104044661   1   4   0
```

My current solution does the job - but I suspect that it is quite cumbersome and I'd be very interested to learn a more elegant solution. Please limit your solutions to UNIX system only, and use the simpler version of awk rather than gawk.

Here's my solution:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NF>1{a[$1"\t"$2"\t"$3] = a[$1"\t"$2"\t"$3]","$4"~"$5};END{for(i in a) {n=split(a[i],g,",")-1; printf i"\t" ;for(z=2;z<=n+1;z++){split(g[z],w,"~"); if(w[1]!=""){printf "%s",w[1]"\t"w[2]"\t";}}printf "\n"}}'|sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2n|awk '{printf "%s",$0;for(i=NF+1;i<=9;i++){printf "%s",0"\t"};printf "\n"}' |awk -F"\t" '{OFS="\t"}{$($4+9)=$5;$($6+9)=$7;$($8+9)=$9;print $0}'|awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=12; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = 0 }; 1'|awk -F "\t" '{OFS="\t"}{print $1,$2,$3,$10,$11,$12}'
```

Comment: s/the simpler version of/POSIX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ curr = $1 FS $2 FS $3 }
curr != prev { if (NR>1) prt(); prev=curr }
{ cnt[$4] += $5 }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    print prev, cnt[1]+0, cnt[2]+0, cnt[3]+0
    delete cnt
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
chrX    93554661        94234661        0       5       3
chrX    94234661        94674661        1       0       0
chrX    95044661        96804661        4       1       6
chrX    96804661        97684661        4       0       0
chrX    97684661        98964661        3       0       0
chrX    98964661        99724661        0       0       0
chrX    99724661        101124661       4       0       0
chrX    101124661       101524661       4       0       0
chrX    101524661       103124661       5       0       1
chrX    103124661       103444661       0       0       2
chrX    103444661       104044661       1       4       0
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Input_file is same as shown sample and you are not worried about the order about the output should be same as Input_file then following may help you in same.

```
awk '
{
  a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]+=$5;
  b[$1 FS $2 FS $3]
}
END{
  for(i in b){
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",i,a[i FS "1"]?a[i FS "1"]:0,a[i FS "2"]?a[i FS "2"]:0, a[i FS "3"]?a[i FS "3"]:0)
}
}
'   Input_file
```

**EDIT:** If you need your output to be same sequence as per Input_file then following may help you in same.

```
awk '
!b[$1 FS $2 FS $3]{
  c[++i]=$1 FS $2 FS $3
}
{
a[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]+=$5;
b[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=$1 FS $2 FS $3
}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n",c[j],a[b[c[j]] FS "1"]?a[b[c[j]] FS "1"]:0,a[b[c[j]] FS "2"]?a[b[c[j]] FS "2"]:0, a[b[c[j]] FS "3"]?a[c[j] FS "3"]:0)
}
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
chrX 93554661 94234661 0 5 3
chrX 94234661 94674661 1 0 0
chrX 95044661 96804661 4 1 6
chrX 96804661 97684661 4 0 0
chrX 97684661 98964661 3 0 0
chrX 98964661 99724661 0 0 0
chrX 99724661 101124661 4 0 0
chrX 101124661 101524661 4 0 0
chrX 101524661 103124661 5 0 1
chrX 103124661 103444661 0 0 2
chrX 103444661 104044661 1 4 0
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this: I'm assuming your data is tab-separated

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,3n file | awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    function init()   { v[1] = v[2] = v[3] = 0 }
    function output() { print prev, v[1], v[2], v[3] }
                { key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 }
    NR == 1     { prev = key; init() }
    key != prev { output(); init() }
                { v[$4] = $5; prev = key }
    END         { output() }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not assuming that the input is ordered:

```
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
!sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3]{
   sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3] = "000"
}
{
   values = sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3]
   if ($4 > 0)
      sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3] = substr(values, 1, $4 - 1) substr(values, $4, 1) + $5 substr(values, $4 + 1, 3 - $4)
}
END {
   for (i in sum) {
      print i, substr(sum[i],1,1), substr(sum[i],2,1), substr(sum[i],3,1)
   }
}

$ awk -f test.awk input.txt
chrX    103444661   104044661   1   4   0
chrX    99724661    101124661   4   0   0
chrX    95044661    96804661    4   1   6
chrX    93554661    94234661    0   5   3
chrX    96804661    97684661    4   0   0
chrX    101124661   101524661   4   0   0
chrX    103124661   103444661   0   0   2
chrX    94234661    94674661    1   0   0
chrX    98964661    99724661    0   0   0
chrX    101524661   103124661   5   0   1
chrX    97684661    98964661    3   0   0
```